# Adding php.ini file to root crashes site

Tags: php, upload

My client's site is on name.com and in order to change the upload limit, I think i need to place a php.ini file in the web root. But Craft crashes when I add it. The site is fine when I remove it. Anyone know why?

They're uploading video and Craft is giving me the 8MB upload limit problem.

Changing the limit in the Craft config file isn't solving it.

Comment: What do you mean "crashes"? Do you get error messages? White screen? Anything in any files?

Comment: It's the gray screen, with the copy "Service Unavailable. Our site is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later."

Comment: That usually just means that Craft is in maintenance mode and/or needs to be updated. What if you try to load the control panel?

Comment: Loading the control panel with the php.ini file in the root gives me this screen: "Error error

Craft requires the PDO extension to operate.

The above error occurred when the Web server was processing your request.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Thank you."

Comment: Soo... looks like you need to install the PDO extension. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: No idea why that error would only show up when you add a php.ini file. I'd contact the host and let them know what you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout a few different log files to see if they can help out.

1. `craft/storage/logs/phperrors.log`
2. If you're running apache, the apache log files
3. If you're running php on ngix or apache, the php log files

Answer (score 1):

I am no system admin expert, but depending on how PHP is compiled and running on the server (either as a module or CGI) will determine if you can use a php.ini file.

If the server is displaying an error message with the php.ini file, try adding `php_value upload_max_filesize 20M` to your .htaccess file.